# Multithreaded Kafka Consumer in .NetCore

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I want to implement multi-threaded Kafka consumer in .NetCore which is given in the image below. In java, we can retrieve multiple records using Poll method and can get records of each partition. I want to implement the same thing in .net.

[image]

Java implementation.

```
while (!stopped.get()) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(100, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
     records.partitions().forEach(partition -> {
         List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition);
         Task task = new Task(partitionRecords);
         executor.submit(task);
         activeTasks.put(partition, task);
    });
}
```

My consumer code in .net core.

```
        using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(
            configuration.AsEnumerable())
            .SetErrorHandler((_, eb) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {eb.Reason}"))
            .SetStatisticsHandler((_, json) => Console.WriteLine($"Statistics: {json}"))
            .SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Assigned Partitions: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
            })
            .SetPartitionsRevokedHandler((c, partitions) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Revoking Assignment: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
            })
            .Build();
        consumer.Subscribe(topicList);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var cr = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);
                Console.WriteLine($"Consumed event from topic {cr.Topic} with value {cr.Message.Value}. Offset: {cr.Offset}, Partition: {cr.Partition.Value}");
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Ctrl-C was pressed.
        }
        finally
        {
            consumer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please show your attempts to add multi threading